# angular js dynamic directive passing model attribute

Tags: angularjs

I knwo that are many relevant posts about how creating dynamic directive mapping in angular but I cannot find anything similar in my case. As the description suggests I am trying to make a dynamic directive where depending the value of an **object attribute** the html is changed. I simplified my problem to this case:

I have a list of object "Widget" which has an attribute name 'type'. I want depending on the type attribute of this list to render html depending on the attribute. To be more specific the Widget.type can have 3 values for example: widget1,widget2 . So in my case I want the directive to return the file widget*.html. (widget1.html for widget type "widget1" etc). Though I pass the argument to the directive using attributes, the value is not evaluated and the string widget.type is return.

Can you help me?
Thx in advance.

app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("MainCtrl", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   function Widget(type){
     this.type=type;
    }

    $scope.widgets=[];

    $scope.widgets.push(new Widget('widget1'),new Widget('widget2'),new Widget('widget3'));



});

app.directive('widget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            obj: '='
        },
        templateUrl: function(element,attr){
            //console.log(attr);
            console.log(attr.obj);
            return attr.obj+'.html';
        }
    }

});
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MainCtrl">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

    <!-- css  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- utilities  -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

   <!--  angular module file -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>



  </head>

  <body  ng-controller="myCtrl">

                <div  ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
                  {{widget.type}}

                    <widget obj='widget.type'   ></widget>
                </div>

    </body>
```

widget1.html file:

```
<div class="widget">
    widget1:{{widget.type}}
</div>
```

widget2.html,widget3.html are the same

Notice the console output in the directive.

I created a plunker so it's easier to notice the problem:http://plnkr.co/edit/ulBSQQrqpSV9g3BNGRhO?p=preview

Comment: Console error: Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: widget.type.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found). You don't have that html file, do you?

Comment: @matmo  widget.type.html  shouldn't be like this. The expression widget.type should evaluate to the according type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example with your directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/XAXy5RGLnvUZIoRj5xAs?p=preview

Secone example without your directive:

```
<div  ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
   <!--{{widget.type}}-->
   <div ng-include="widget.template"></div> 
</div>
```

Note: additional property in your Widget-object. Easier to handle.

First one is not as beautiful as the example without the directive, becaue your scope-variable of the directive has to be the same as the variable in your templates ('widget'). I like the second example much more.

Comment: Though it's a great workaround and pretty straightforward , is there any way to make it work by my way? In my case the problem is simple, but what about a more complex one where more calculations must be done? I can't think any specific example but I wanted to pass an 'argument' to the directive in the first place...

Comment: It's still a argument, but you use 'widget' in your template e.g. in widget.html you use {{widget.type}}. So your attribute of the directive has to be named also 'widget', but it's still an argument. And the first example should be the one which is your way or do I miss something? If not, mark as solution.

Calculation inside the directive? I don't know exactly whats your point of interest, but this would be helpful: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals